# How to get autocomplete for magic method __call - PHP Editors

Tags: php, autocomplete, editor, code-formatting

we can have an autocomplete in PHP Editors for a class like:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Controller
 * @property foo foo
*/
class Controller {
   public function bar() {
      $this->foo-> // autocomplete here
   }
}

class foo() {
}
```

but if i want an auto complete for a magic method like `__call` how is that possible

example below:

```
<?php

Class Controller {

   public function __call($function, $arguments) {
      if($function == 'foo') {
         // some logic here
      }
   }
}

Class Home extends Controller {
   public function somefunction() {
      $this-> // should have an autocomplete of foo
   }
}
```

any idea how could this be achieved to configure auto-complete in PHP Editors

*I use PHP-Storm if there is something specific*

Comment: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html

Comment: great! Thanks @MarkBaker, could you post it as an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `@method` phpdoc tag to get autocomplete for magic methods

here is a code example for you:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Controller
 * @method mixed foo() foo($parametersHere) explanation of the function
 */
Class Controller {

   public function __call($function, $arguments) {
      if($function == 'foo') {
         // some logic here
      }
   }
}
```

This should work well